# Setting Vuelidate custom error messages for built-in validators globally

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuelidate

I'm using the latest version of Vuelidate with Vue 3. Is there a way to globally set the error messages for the built-in validators? I see this section within the docs where it says to use the `withMessage` function on the helper object, like this:

```js
import { required, helpers } from '@vuelidate/validators'

const validations = {
  name: {
    required: helpers.withMessage('This field cannot be empty', required)
  }
}
```

But this looks like it needs to be set each time we build the rules object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create file with wrappers for vuelidate validators and use them in your app.

**validators.js**

```js
import { helpers, minLength, required } from '@vuelidate/validators';

export const required$ = helpers.withMessage('This field cannot be empty', required)

export const phoneMinLength$ = (min: number) => helpers.withMessage(
  ({ $params}) => `Phone number should contain ${$params.min} digits.`, minLength(min)
)
```

then in your app:

```js
import { required$, phoneMinLength$ } from './validators'

...
validations() {
    return {
      form: {
        phone: {
          minLength: phoneMinLength$(9),
          required$,
        }
      }
    }
  },
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yeah, that's the only approach I had thought of too, so it sounds like that's the direction I'll be heading in.